# My UIView or UIImage is always in blank

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I'm trying to take a picture from my `UIView`, namely I make a screenshot from my `UIView` but always the `UIImage` is in blank and I don't know why. And I tested with my iPhone and take a picture in blank. :(

I put `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`  and added `QuartzCore.framework`.

Could someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)savePhoto:(id)sender
{    
    UIImage *imageCaptured = [self imageFromView:self.view];

    NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"];

    // Write a UIImage to JPEG with minimum compression (best quality)
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageCaptured) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];

    // Let's check to see if files were successfully written...

    // Create file manager
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Point to Document directory
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

    // Write out the contents of home directory to console
    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
}

- (UIImage *) imageFromView:(UIView *)view 
{    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,372));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer drawInContext:context];
    UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [imageView setImage:screenShot];
    return  screenShot;
}
```

Comment: Not the answer to your problem, but why are you hardcoding the image size instead of using `view.bounds.size`?

Comment: Also, your way of querying the Documents directory is wrong. Use something like `NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: but.. i have a problem,  now take me a screenshot from all view with controllnavigation and tabbar but i only want that start at x and y position with a heigth and width

Comment: Hmmm, try setting the width and size in your call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, then translate the context by `-x` and `-y` via `CGContextTranslateCTM`.

Comment: why do you do - [imageView setImage:screenShot]; in imageFromView function?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your line of

```
 [view.layer drawInContext:context];
```

to

```
[view.layer renderInContext:context];
```